# Subclassing the System Menu

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, menu

I have defined an owner drawn menu class. The class takes into account the `MeasureItem` issues of the system menu defined in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7021/MFC-extension-library-A-plugin-to-handle-owner-dra#problem3) (ie adjusting the custom measurements based on whether the menu is system menu or not). However the problem I'm having is subclassing the system menu at the correct time.

At the moment I have used both of the following code snippets to attempt to subclass it (in an overriden [`CFrameWnd::LoadFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e3h089yt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)):

1. Attempt 1: `mSysMenu` is a subclass of `CMenu`, which has also overridden `Attach` to automatically set the menu to owner draw (the bool parameter is just passed to notify whether it is a system menu or not)

   ```
   mSysMenu.Attach(GetSystemMenu(FALSE)->GetSafeHmenu(), true);
   ```

   This one fails when I right-click the taskbar button, generating 3 assertions in `wincore.cpp` (in `CWnd::OnMeasureItem`) and an ugly, deformed owner drawn menu - something to do with the `_AFX_THREAD_STATE` class.
   However when I call `TrackPopupMenu` on it from `OnLButtonDown` BEFORE I right click the task bar, eveything goes fine.
2. Attempt 2: This one just creates a similarly deformed menu measurement but without any signs of owner drawn attempts

   ```
   CVSPMenu* sysMenu = (CVSPMenu*)CMenu::FromHandle(GetSystemMenu(FALSE)->GetSafeHmenu());
   sysMenu->SetOwnderDrawn(true);
   ```

I've also tried doing things in `OnInitMenuPopup` but the menu pointer passed in doesn't seem to be and use (just causing assertions and failing).

So my question is, how and where do I subclass the system menu?

Comment: This sounds like a really tough approach.  Are you sure you need to subclass the menu, and not just customize it from a subclassed window?

Comment: Its cool I solved the problem. It turns out that the custom drawn system menu was only properly measured if the call was via TrackPopupMenu (obviously on some hidden level the system menu is displayed via an alternative method). So I overrode the  undocumented 0x0313 message and called TrackPopupMenu there which measured it all correctly etc :)

Comment: The Menu pointer passed to OnInitMenuPopup for the system menu is the default SystemMenu if you haven't called GetSystemMenu() before and cannot be modified. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/28/10016691.aspx

Comment: That's unbelievably useful info! Its so hard to find info on the system menu, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Because that MSDN link is dead, I've resurrected it via web.archive, and pasted the relevant text below.

https://web.archive.org/web/20140413053140/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/05/28/10016691.aspx

> I mentioned last time that there's an optimization in the treatment
>   of the system menu which significantly reduces the number of menus in
>   the system.
>
> When a window has the WS_SYSMENU window style, it has a system menu,
>   but until somebody calls Get­System­Menu on that window, nobody knows
>   what its menu handle is. Until that point, the window manager doesn't
>   actually have to commit to creating a menu for the window; it can just
>   pretend that the window has one. (This technique goes by the fancy
>   name lazy initialization.)
>
> The window manager creates a global default system menu which contains
>   the standard system menu items. If somebody presses Alt+Space or
>   otherwise calls up the system menu for a window that has never had
>   Get­System­Menu called on it, the window manager just uses the global
>   default system menu, since it knows that nobody has customized the
>   menu. (You can't customize a menu you don't have the handle to!) Since
>   most people never customize their system menu, this optimization
>   avoids cluttering the desktop heap with identical copies of the same
>   menu. This was a particularly important optimization back in the
>   16-bit days, when all window manager objects had to fit into a single
>   64KB heap (known as System Resources).
>
> If you are really sneaky, you can catch a glimpse of the elusive
>   global default system menu as it whizzes by: As with any other popup
>   menu, the handle to the menu being displayed is passed to your
>   window's WM_INIT­MENU­POPUP, and if your program has never called
>   Get­System­Menu, the handle that you will see is the global default
>   system menu. Mind you, you can't do much to this menu, since the
>   window manager blocks any attempt to modify it. (Otherwise, your
>   program's menu modification would have an unintended effect on the
>   menus of other programs!)
>
> Therefore, if your program is in the habit of modifying its system
>   menu in its WM_INIT­MENU­POPUP handler, you should stick a dummy call
>   to Get­System­Menu in your WM_CREATE handler to force your system menu
>   to change from a pretend system menu to a real one.